# Using logback.xml with Scala Worksheet

Tags: scala, scala-ide, slick

Scala Worsheet sets the logger output to debug, which causes third-party libraries (Slick in this case) to print out heaps of logging info. Is there any way I customise the logger to put specific libraries at 'info' level.

I have a logback.xml file in my resources directory, but Scala Worksheet ignores this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this was a problem with the Scala-IDE or Worksheet nightly's. After a recent update, the Worksheet stopped printing out debug info for external libraries. Great!